# What's a more efficient way of obtaining money in Factions?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I love the popular Minecraft server game Factions, but I have been really annoyed at some great servers versions of Factions; they all now have microtransactions, which give lots of epic bonuses. They're really expensive, though, and I don't want to pay that. Using in-game money, you need a lot of it to match the real money bonuses. Often the only way of getting this in-game money is to sit at your inefficient house (because you didn't buy better materials with real cash) and farm, or attempt to kill other players with your starter materials, which are much worse, and end up dying a lot. I need to know if there is any other way of getting money efficiently without dying a million times or sitting for an hour farming and getting barely anything.

Comment: I have flagged to close this question as this is blatantly off topic and dosent belong on this site

Comment: @Cameron.C Actually, there's a pretty specific question in here.  There's definitely something we can help with.  I've removed the rant, however, to focus more on the question being asked, without all the cruft.

Comment: I could only recommend the faction server choicecraft they don't give ridiculous previliges but its a very hardcore server with a live map

Comment: @Frank thanks for helping me understand the question better now I can give a real answer without thinking its a rant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really broad question, and that I have no clue which server you're playing on (as each server configures the rules and worlds differently).

---

As you've probably already realized, the micro-transactions are meant to do three things:

1. Incentive you to spend money on in-game ranks.
2. Provide you a boost that will take *ages* to obtain fairly (with nobody else trying to kill you), for example; diamond gear in one transaction.*
3. Give you an edge (in other means) against other players, for example; cosmetically (ie. flying in lobbies or color chat).

*This is against the Mojang EULA.

---

Aside from the blanting obvious: "Farm", there are several things that can be suggested you can do:

- If you go for the farming method, and there is an allowed teleport between your base (or `/home`) and the shop, you'll want to set up a base *far* away from spawn; as far as you can get to minimize your chances of being found and killed.
  Also, don't forget to apply any standard hidden-base conventions while building it, and expand **as much as possible**.
  Finally, leave an alt on the server to ensure the crops keep growing (chunks are loaded).
- Should you choose to go for the PvP option, make sure you have friends who can assist you, as [unless the other person is using aim-hacks] - He can't battle three people at once, especially when they're not clumped together (ie. one to the left, to the right and behind/in front).
  Also, only target lone wolves (players not in a group).
  In effect, staying apart will render a fully-charged swing useless as the angle of swipe is not large enough (for 1.9 ONW), and that the defending player is only able to focus on one person at a time while another comes from the back, etc. (all versions)
- Bring multiple accounts (they do not need to be played by multiple people). This way, you can reap the starting gear and any time-based kits/drops/whatever multiple times.

If you feel that the server you're playing on is deliberately making it difficult to play fairly without buying gear from the shop, it's probably a cash-grab server. In that case, it'd be better to move on.
And also [report](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1jUIPyvww8E5LfzrGDJ828AtuucPOf2gE87i06g7xT-U/viewform?usp=send_form) it. If it seems dodgy, it probably is.

You can see this by the following general traits (general, open to subjectivity and opinion):

- Ranks that go into the thousands of dollars. (A general guideline is ranks shouldn't be more than $300 or 6 months of rent^)
- It is impossible to sell anything for server money, and the rate that you get money is that it'll take weeks to even buy iron.
- Servers that do not let you do vanilla actions without a paid rank (ie. mine Diamond). Those that ask you to register for free are alright; they're trying to break griefers and those who cheat their way to Diamond.

^Actual amount in cash is open to debate

Comment: Thank you for that, I know about the EULA as i have made my own Minecraft servers. These are some great tips but i have one question. How do I report Minecraft servers.

Comment: @GoldNugget8 You just click the link in the post. [This one or the one that is attached to the word 'report'](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1jUIPyvww8E5LfzrGDJ828AtuucPOf2gE87i06g7xT-U/viewform?usp=send_form)

Comment: Lol, i missed that. Thank you. I have a long list of servers that violate the EULA.